# change increment and decrement number with two button React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {count : 0}

    this.M = {Message : " "}
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    this.result = this.result.bind(this);
    this.result();

  }

  increment(){
    this.setState({count : this.state.count + 1}) ;
    this.result()
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  decrement() {
    this.setState({count : this.state.count - 1});
    this.result()
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  result() {
    if (this.state.count >0)
    {
      this.forceUpdate();
      //  this.setState({Message : "positive"});
      this.M.Message = "Positive";
      // this.forceUpdate();
    } else 
    {  
      this.M.Message = "Negative";
      // this.forceUpdate();

      // this.setState({Message : "NEGATIVE "});

    }
    this.forceUpdate();
   
  }



// }
render() {
    return (
      <View>
                <Text style = {{margin: 45, fontSize: 22}}>you have  {this.state.count} Coin</Text>
                <Button 
                      onPress={this.increment}
                      title="win Coin "
                      color="#841584" />
                <Button
                      onPress = {this.decrement}
                      title="lose Coin"
                      color="#841584" />


                      <Text style = {{fontSize : 28}}> Result :  {this.M.Message} </Text>
       </View>
    )  
  }
}
```

**the bug is when the count equal 0 or -1 it has the result of the prevents exemple one the user click on lose Coin the result is -1 so the  message is "negative" but when he click another time  on the button win coin the result get 0 and the result is not Positive but Negative the precedent result and just for the two result is 0 and -1 **

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: this.state.count > 0 makes 1, 2, 3.. Positive and 0, -1, -2... Negative. So when user clicks on win coin and the count is 0 the Message should be Negative. You need to change the if statement.

Comment: @kudlas 0,1,2,3 ... => result message = POSITIVE else NEGATIVE

Comment: @gustavozapata i try it >-1 or >= 0 its the same probleme

Answer (score 1):

I found out the source of the problem. As you may know, this.setState() is asynchronous. You can achieve the result you want by simply changing the setState to this

```
increment() {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }, () => {
    this.result();
    this.forceUpdate();
  });
}
```

Make sure you also change 'decrement' too.